# Even and Odd rows using ForEach (SwiftUI)

Tags: list, foreach, swiftui

What is the best way to distinguish even and odd rows in ForEach loop? Contents of the loop is not numbers (i.e. User struct), and it can be filtered using search phrase (using just index of item in array is not applicable in that way, I think). I need to change a color of that rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand question correctly, you can use indices of your data array and check condition `index % 2 == 1` (because indices begins from 0) for odd rows. For filtered data I suggest computed value:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct HighlightingRowData: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
}

final class SomeData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: [HighlightingRowData] = [HighlightingRowData(title: "R. Martin"), HighlightingRowData(title: "McConell"), HighlightingRowData(title: "London"), HighlightingRowData(title: "London")]
}

struct HighlitedRowsInList: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var someData: SomeData
    @State private var searchedText = ""
    private var filteredData: [HighlightingRowData] {
        return searchedText == "" ? someData.data : someData.data.filter { $0.title.contains(searchedText) }
    }

    var body: some View {

        List {

            TextField("filter", text: $searchedText)

            ForEach(filteredData.indices, id: \.self) { rowIndex in
                HStack {
                    Text(self.filteredData[rowIndex].title)
                    Spacer()
                }
                    .background(rowIndex % 2 == 1 ? Color.yellow : Color.clear)
            }

        }
    }
}

struct HighlitedRowsInList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HighlitedRowsInList()
            .environmentObject(SomeData())
    }
}
```

you can achieve something like this with this code:

[image]